# Android Emulator looks very blurry and pixilated

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

The problem happens on every Linux distro, making UI design a nightmare.

KVM is installed and configured, tried on both Intel and Nvidia, Wayland, X11 and Xcb.

Any solution or insight to what may be causing the issue?

Comment: what is the issue? ... please add a picture

Comment: it's an anti-aliasing problem with android emulator.

Comment: wouldn't that be dependent on which emulator you are using?